# Grafana: How can I use secret-form-field directive in Grafana?

Tags: angular, grafana

I am trying to use directive and passing it label="My Label" but my label does not show up in the UI, instead I get the default "Password" as my label.

I think passing 'label' as an option in the following file line 88 will fix the issue?
https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/c9b11bfc7ae1ce89d737c938993db5fa0e421fdb/public/app/core/angular_wrappers.ts

I opened a ticket about this on github but I don't understand the answer.

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/20258

Are they suggesting I write my config editor using react instead of trying to pass "label" to secret-form-field directive?

Answer (score -1):

whatever component you are passing the props to like

```html
<ng-container>
  <app-component *ngFor="let item of itemsToLoopOver" [input]="item.text"></app-component>
</ng-container>
```

### component1.ts

```js
  @Input() private textToShow: string;
```

### component1.html

```html
<div>
  {{ textToShow }}
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer, can you please be more descriptive?